# SharePoint An unexpected error: Not firing button_Click function and goes to Web parts maintenance page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

[image]I have dropped a webpart on publishing page but when i click on (process)button it transfer me to this error:

> Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred. Web
>   Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page
>   to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more
>   information, contact your site administrator.

My webpart contains a search button and a process button and a gridview, functionality of process button is to read an excel file and display it in a gridview the whole process is working fine on other site but is not working on my QA site where testing is going on and because of this I can not debugging[image: Snapshot]

scenario is I have to select file and process.

can anybody helps me out why it is transferring me to the "`Web Parts Maintenance Page`"

the same thing is working fine on the other site

Answer (score 0):

[Similar question was asked here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790305/sharepoint-2013-sorry-something-went-wrong-error)

You will see that on the error page, there is a correlation ID and timestamp of the error.  You will need to go into the logs of Sharepoint (something like microsoft shared/15/logs), find the ID corresponding to the error, and this log will show you what was changed that is causing this error.

Comment: where can i find the log file?

Comment: It might be different for you, but it can be found in program files/common files/microsoft shared/(15 or 14)/logs.  Then go through the most recent logs to find the correlation ID matching the one in the error report.  I wish we could give you a more straightforward answer, but this error can be caused by a number of things.  It won't be clear until you check the logs.

Comment: If you are unsure of what you are looking for, it will be a text document containing what looks like compilation error messages, like you would see on any IDE, followed by a string of characters.  Those characters are the corr ID, and the ID that matches your will show what is causing the error that bring you to the screen.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/nujbvw1sv/ 

there is no log file

Comment: Then, for clarification, did you delete something on the publishing page, and then it is causing the error when you click the processing button?  If that is the case, maybe the actual processing function depended (in some way) on the deleted element.

Comment: no nothing is deleted from the page.
the same function is working on the other site

Comment: My last piece of advice is that maybe it is a broke site collection causing the error.  Try using Sharepoint Designer to restore it.  Other than this, like I said, this error can be caused by a number of issues.  Unless you can view the log files, it's going to be a game of guess and check until you find the culprit.

Comment: i have found the log files and searching for the error.

Comment: By the way thanks for your log advice it works for me

Answer (score 0):

one thing i can think of is, is it using the correct list that its pulling out the data into the gridview? are you using the correct column names between the gridview and the list on the site??

its given you an id in the error page... you need to copy that id and search on the log file using that id in 14 or 15 hive!!!

Comment: Process button is not using any sort of list. it is just reading the excel file and display data in gridview

Comment: what error does it show in the log file?, can you post only the process button code?

Comment: where can i find the log file?

Comment: c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs , that is for 2010 if 2013 than change 14 to 15! obviously this would be on the server itself where sharepoint is hosted!

Comment: there is no log file in it that you have asking for.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/nujbvw1sv/

Comment: with the log file sort by date to get the lates version at the top within the folder logs... now reproduce the error again by clicking the button and then go back to the logs and open up the most uptodate log file (should be at top). now once file is open press ctrl + f to search file and paste in the error code that is generated on the error page and you should see the error that its producing!

Comment: thanks Ali i have found the error 
there is an exception in the process button function
working on it 
thanks for helping

Comment: no problem happy to help!

Comment: Either excel is not installed on your QA server or you are not including the Excel required libraries with your wsp file.